# angularjs multiple ng-app call function

Tags: angularjs

I have just started learning AngularJS and created some basic samples however I am stuck with the following problem.

I have created 2 modules and 2 controllers.

I want to call a second ng-app(DivAPP2) function in the first ng-app(DivAPP1)

How to achieve it?

Example:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id='div1' ng-controller="app1controller">
            {{functionAPP2(2)}}  //..Export  4
     </div>

     <div id='div2' ng-controller="app1controller">
            {{functionAPP1(2)}}  //..Export  2
     </div>
   </body>
 <html>

<script language="javascript">

var app1= angular.module("DivAPP1", []);

 app1.controller("app1controller", function($scope ,$http) {


  $scope.functionAPP1=function(str){
      return str;
  }

});

 var app2= angular.module("DivAPP2", []);

 app2.controller("app2controller", function($scope ,$http) {
    $scope.functionAPP2=function(str){
       return str+str;
     }});

 angular.bootstrap(angular.element("#div1"),["DivAPP1"]);
 angular.bootstrap(angular.element("#div2"),["DivAPP2"]);

</script>
```

Comment: Per the documentation, `only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. `

Comment: Go back to the basics...angular docs tutorial. You are starting out with some strange concepts

Comment: Thank all, I reached my goal ,My Example [link]http://jsbin.com/deyumovo/7/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are going to want to do is declare one of your modules as a dependency of the one you are bootstrapping, so:

```
var app2= angular.module("DivAPP2", []);
// your code


var app1= angular.module("DivAPP1", ['DivAPP2']);
```

Then you boostrap your app using `DivAPP1`

Comment: Thank you for your answer lucam

My Example [link]http://jsbin.com/deyumovo/7/edit?html,js,output